# Why is the scroll bar being colored?

Tags: html, css

I was trying to understand the DOM structure
so I added `background-color:red` to the body
but I can't understand why the scroll bar is being colored red as well?

```css
html {

  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;

}

body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: red;

}

#container {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5rem;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="container">
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Also, How do I avoid coloring the scroll bar?
**Edit**
This is how it looks on windows firefox browser and in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/veLmy0q6/)
[image]

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/RIh8TWv — I can't reproduce the problem, I get the browser default when I test that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The color of the scrollbar depends on the browser. Some browers make the scrollbar color to be the same as the background of the scrollable element you are in. This is why the scrollbar is turning red. However, this isn't happening in my browser (Firefox).

Luckily, the default color of the scrollbar can be customized with css by adding this css property to the scrollable element:

```css
.scrollable-element {
  scrollbar-color: red yellow;
}
```

The word "red" will make the scrollbar red, and the word "yellow" will make the scrollbar background yellow. You can customize it however you want.

In the context of your code, you should apply the property to your `html` css selector (and change the colors to whatever you prefer). This is how the css file should look like:

```css
html {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  scrollbar-color: red yellow;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

#container {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5rem;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: auto;
}
```

The scroll-bar-color property does not work on all browsers. You can find more information about it in [this tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/scrollbar-color/).

Comment: I added an image to describe how it looks like.
also can you add the full code so I can mark your answer as correct?

Comment: Sure @lemonface, done!

Comment: Yes, however, `scrollbar-color` and properties like it (`scrollbar-width`, etc.) are ONLY supported in Firefox, and most other browsers use the tedious `::-webkit-scrollbar`, etc. code for such changes, so you may have to consider using that as well.